# How to remove text from String

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I have string as

------=_Part_0_rtkakab

Hello Testing1.
------=_Part_0_rtkakab

I want to change to 
**Hello Testing1.**

What is the best way to do this.

Comment: **Change to** .. or **keep** it?

Comment: Keep , I think. I am just looking for best way.

Comment: Okey, is this the only input or there are more similar ones?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [replace](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replace.htm) if you know the chars to replace or the [substring](http://www.javatpoint.com/substring) if you know the string position.